# RuntimeError: inverse_cuda: For batch 0: U(19536384,19536384) is zero, singular U

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run Image Point augmentation using fastaiv2. When the developers run it in their environment on a fresh install, it works fine, but when I do in colab I cannot get it to work.

I've looked into the `aug_transforms` function to see just where this problem is coming up in and it has to do with augmenting the image points.

Here is the full steps:

```py
!pip install git+https://github.com/fastai/fastai_dev > /dev/null
!pip install Pillow --upgrade # to get libraries

from fastai2.basics import *
from fastai2.callback.all import *
from fastai2.vision.all import *

path = untar_data(URLs.BIWI_HEAD_POSE)
cal = np.genfromtxt(path/'01'/'rgb.cal', skip_footer=6)
def img2txt_name(f): return path/f'{str(f)[:-7]}pose.txt'

def convert_biwi(coords:array):
  x = coords[0] * cal[0][0]/coords[2] + cal[0][2]
  y = coords[1] * cal[1][1]/coords[2] + cal[1][2]
  return tensor([x,y])

def get_ctr(f:Path):
  ctr = np.genfromtxt(img2txt_name(f), skip_header=3)
  return convert_biwi(ctr)

def get_ip(img:PILImage, pts:array): return TensorPoint.create(pts, sz=img.size)

splitter = FuncSplitter(lambda o: o.parent.name=='13')
dblock = DataBlock(blocks=(ImageBlock, PointBlock),
                   get_items=get_image_files,
                   splitter=splitter,
                   get_y=get_ctr)

batch_tfms = [*aug_transforms(size=(120,160), max_warp=0), Normalize(*imagenet_stats)]

dbunch = dblock.databunch(path, path=path, bs=64, batch_tfms=batch_tfms)
dbunch.show_batch(max_n=9, figsize=(9,6)) # breaks here
```

The expected result was to show a batch of augmented images, instead I get a stack trace with the following RuntimeError:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai2/vision/augment.py in affine_coord(x, mat, coord_tfm, sz, mode, pad_mode)
    260     if sz is None: sz = x._meta.get('sz', None)
    261     if coord_tfm is not None: x = coord_tfm(x, invert=True)
--> 262     if mat is not None: x = (x - mat[:,:,2].unsqueeze(1)) @ torch.inverse(mat[:,:,:2].transpose(1,2))
    263     return TensorPoint(x, sz=sz)
    264 

RuntimeError: inverse_cuda: For batch 0: U(19536384,19536384) is zero, singular U.
```

Any thoughts on how to go about this? As I also tried this on my fresh machine and it worked fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what's happening there. The following transform seems to be the guilt: "*aug_transforms(size=(120,160), max_warp=0)". Surprisingly it works when run without GPU.

Comment: One more comment, a similar issue is discussed here https://forums.fast.ai/t/fastai-v2-vision/53528 it is also related to aug_transforms and Colab, seems to work outside Colab according to other contributers to the thread. It might be worth raising it on the forum.

Comment: I made the post on the forum :)

Comment: Looks to be an issue with Magma, they're working on it

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29096